# ec2 インスタンス上で virtualbox を実行することはできる？

Tags: aws, virtualbox

VirtualBox を ec2 インスタンス上で実行しようとして、エラーになりました。

どうやら、 ec2 が利用する Xen と、 VirtualBox が利用する Xen がぶつかっている様子です。

### 質問

- VirtualBox を ec2 で利用することは、原理的に不可能なのでしょうか？
- 迂回策がある場合、それはどのようなものになりますか？

### 出力

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vboxdrv ...
  /etc/rc0.d/K80vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc1.d/K80vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc6.d/K80vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc2.d/S20vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc3.d/S20vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc4.d/S20vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
  /etc/rc5.d/S20vboxdrv -> ../init.d/vboxdrv
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service ...
  /etc/rc0.d/K65vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc1.d/K65vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc6.d/K65vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc2.d/S35vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc3.d/S35vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc4.d/S35vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
  /etc/rc5.d/S35vboxballoonctrl-service -> ../init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vboxautostart-service ...
  /etc/rc0.d/K65vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc1.d/K65vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc6.d/K65vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc2.d/S35vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc3.d/S35vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc4.d/S35vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
  /etc/rc5.d/S35vboxautostart-service -> ../init.d/vboxautostart-service
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/vboxweb-service ...
  /etc/rc0.d/K65vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc1.d/K65vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc6.d/K65vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc2.d/S35vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc3.d/S35vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc4.d/S35vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
  /etc/rc5.d/S35vboxweb-service -> ../init.d/vboxweb-service
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox. To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2はXenの上で動く仮想マシンのサービスですが、
Xenカーネル上ではVirtualBoxはサポートされないので残念ながら無理です。